# Как разметить пространство диска при установке ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

На ноуте два hdd в raid 0. При установке показывает вот такую штуку.

[image]

Куда ее тут устанавливать? В мануалах про такой случай ничего не нашел.

При этом хорошо, чтобы еще осталась win7, установленная рядом, и данные не потерлись.

Comment: насколько можно понять из картинки, у вас создано два раздела, **полностью** занимающих блочное устройство. создавать дополнительные разделы просто негде.

Comment: почему негде? место свободное есть. вот что показывает: http://i80.fastpic.ru/big/2016/0424/25/769b5fa3a1e54c6c2fa9276571763725.png

Comment: @watenix Как вариант, установите Linux прямо в своей семёрке. Устанавливаем VirtualBox и в нем уже Linux. Как это сделать смотрите [тут](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bHGeH0JmE48)

Comment: под «местом» вы подразумеваете пространство в файловой системе, созданной внутри раздела. я же говорю о блочном устройстве, которое, судя по картинке, полностью занято. да, конечно, файловую систему можно «ужать», а затем «ужать» и раздел, ею занимаемый. в результате на блочном устройстве появится неразмеченное пространство, которое и можно будет использовать для создания новых разделов.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, подробнее можно, как это сделать? Перед установкой выполнил дефрагментацию.

Comment: это совершенно другой вопрос, не имеющий отношения к вами заданному.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, имеет отношение. По вашим же словам, чтобы установить нужно выделить место. Собственно вопрос: как это сделать на raid0?

Comment: *как это сделать на raid0?* — переформулируйте вопрос или задайте новый с помощью кнопки «задать вопрос» в правом верхнем углу страницы. внести исправления в вопрос можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, готово) Собственно, как разменитить диск для устновки ubuntu?

Answer (score 3):

[картинки здесь](https://askubuntu.com/a/343370/416190).

1. выберите в списке раздел, который можно «ужать».
2. нажмите <kbd>change</kbd> и уменьшите раздел.
3. после этого в списке разделов должна появиться запись о свободном пространстве на носителе, которое и можно использовать для установки.

---

**обновление**

если установщик не предлагает возможности изменять размеры разделов, попробуйте прекратить установку и изменить размеры разделов, например, с помощью программы [*gparted*](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/GParted) (должна входить в состав установочного live-образа, которым вы, судя по всему, пользуетесь).

если и с помощью *gparted* ничего не выйдет, загрузите *ms/windows* и уменьшите нужный раздел её «нативными» средствами.

Comment: Конечно я читал этот мануал и еще кучу других. Но мне надо для raid0. Вот что у меня выходит: http://images.vfl.ru/ii/1461500225/d8808211/12425605.png

Comment: насколько я вижу из приведённой вами картинки, установщик отлично разобрался с логическим объединением ваших физических дисков. так что просто попробуйте следовать инструкции.

Comment: инструкция не совсем соответствует. При попытке изменения показывается такое оконо:
http://images.vfl.ru/ii/1461500855/f0cf05da/12425837.png

Comment: какие пункты присутствуют в списке?

Comment: там выбор типа фаловой системы: ntfs, fat, ext, файл подкачки и д.р.

Comment: замечательно. и если выбрать тип файловой системы, который соответствует реальности (ntfs), что происходит дальше?

Comment: поставилась точка монтирования /windows. Что дальше делать? 
Вот скриншот http://images.vfl.ru/ii/1461501713/de495cd4/12426027.png

Comment: вот еще скриншот:
http://images.vfl.ru/ii/1461502350/cce4639d/12426162.png

Comment: @watenix, обновил ответ.